# Vue / Vuex : paste event triggered before input binded value is updated

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a simple form in a component :

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="submitSearch">
    <input v-model="objId" @paste="submitSearch">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and

```
var searchForm = {
    methods :   {
        submitSearch() { 
            store.dispatch('submitSearch')
        }
    },
    computed : {
      objId: {
        get () {
          return ...
        },
        set (id) {
          store.commit('objId', id)
        }
      }
    },
    ...
};
```

It works well when typing and submitting, however when pasting a value `submitSearch` is called just before `objId` is updated so it doesn't. Is there a consise and vue-friendly way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using `nextTick()` :

```
submitSearch() { 
    Vue.nextTick().then(function () {
        store.dispatch('submitSearch')
    })
}
```

Not sure if it's the recommended way but it works well and avoid extra variables.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do it is have a local variable `isPaste` and set it to `true`, when the `paste` event is triggered. Then also register an `input` event which will trigger after the `paste` event and check if `isPaste` is `true`. If it is, then submit and set `isPaste` to `false` again.

```
<input v-model="objId" @paste="paste" @input="input">


data(): {
  return {
    isPaste: false
  }
},
methods: {
  paste() {
    this.isPaste = true;
  },
  input() {
    if (this.isPaste) {
      store.dispatch('submitSearch');
      isPaste = false;
    }
  }
}
```